# Connecting to CosmosDB using MongoDB API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I recently completed a MEAN app locally on my machine that has data in a MongoDB that I am reading from in my app. Now I am trying to deploy this using azure. I have already got all of my Node, express and angular files to my resource group and have deployed those. I can access my app at philosophe-quotidien-app-git.azurewebsites.net
But for the app to work, it needs to read data from a MongoDB database. 
I followed these steps: https://github.com/lostintangent/node-azure#provisioning-a-mongodb-server

I have an Azure CosmosDB account and I configured the connection string and my app uses an environment variable to connect to the MongoDB instance. But I am consistently getting CONNECTION_REFUSED errors. The app works fine locally.

What do I need to do here?

Comment: Seems your question is actually about "Connecting to CosmosDB" then. That is how you should title your question. Also the "tags" you attach to questions here are meant to relate to "what your question is about". Don't simply apply tags based on "all tech I use in my stack". Because that is the wrong thing to do, and the people watching those other tags, really don't care for questions that are actually about connecting to CosmosDB.

Comment: Just to validate, did you spin up a Cosmos DB cluster using the MongoDB API per [Azure Cosmos DB: Migrate an existing Node.js MongoDB web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-nodejs)?

Comment: What's your connection string? What code do you use to establish the connection? Did you choose DocumentDB or MongoDB api? As written, there's not much anyone can do to help. Please edit your question accordingly. (and if you do include your connection string, please don't expose real credentials!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.
@DennyLee I created a cosmosdb account within the same resource group that my app is deployed. I obtained the connection string for that db and then set it equal to an environment variable that holds the port for mongoose to connect to at my node backend. I used the commands here: https://github.com/lostintangent/node-azure#provisioning-a-mongodb-server 

$MONGODB_URL=$(az cosmosdb list-connection-strings -n $COSMOSDB_NAME -otsv --query "connectionStrings[0].connectionString")

and 

az webapp config appsettings set --settings MONGODB_URL=$MONGODB_URL

Comment: Since I have a lot of data stored in a local MongoDB instance on my PC that cosmosdb doesn't have (because the document explorer tab in azure shows there are no documents here), I also tried to import the data using the mongoimport.exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-migrate

Comment: To clarify, did you create a Cosmos DB database or a Cosmos DB Mongo API database?

Comment: @DennyLee Sorry i am a little exasperating but what is the difference between the two? I used the az cosmosdb create -n $COSMOSDB_NAME --kind MongoDB command to create it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I was asking whether the `--kind MongoDB` command was being used to create it.  Could you email us at [Ask Azure Cosmos DB](mailto:askcosmosdb@microsoft.com) and perhaps we can help debug?